# React native: images with space in name won't load in IOS (device, not https issue)

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile-development

Images with spaces in their name won't load in IOS, for android it worked by replacing the spaces with %20, but this solution didn't work on ios. React native.

I m loading the images remotely using uri, in a normal Image container. images without space load fine.

Comment: how are you trying to load them? in webView? html? question needs some more info

Comment: normal Image component

Comment: hmm, if it works for Android and not for iOS I suspect it to be related to file system permissions.

Comment: Are other images (without space in name) loading just fine?

Comment: yes images without space in uri work just fine... and in android both work

Comment: Please add your `image_url` to create working example for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Image source={{uri: fileName.replace(/ /g, '%20')}} style={styles.image} />
```

works on react-native@0.59.5

Answer (score 3):

```js
encodeURI("http://www.yourdomain.tld/sample image.jpg")
```

## Output

```js
http://www.yourdomain.tld/sample image.jpg

to

http://www.yourdomain.tld/sample%20image.jpg
```

## Usage

```js
<Image source={{uri: encodeURI(fileUri)}} />
```

the best way is to use the js builtin javascript function [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

because we also have to convert some special characters in URLs